# Why is the anchor tag smaller than the child image?

Tags: html, css

On my site, http://www.redsquiggli.es under the "Contact Me" section, why are my anchor tags smaller (and underneath) the images that they contain?

Shouldn't the anchor be bigger (with it's specified padding) than it's contents?

Also, I've been trying to get those two icons to be vertically centered in the p tag that the anchor is in... auto margining is not working there either. What's the reason for that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make the a tags display:inline-block; and they will surround the images as you expect, and they will be horizontally centered (as they already are) by the text-align: centre; you have set globally.

You can't vertically align an element in css unless you use a table. Although you can make divs behave like tables with some css, but this will not work in IE: [link text](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Web-Style-Sheets/Creating-DIVbased-CSS-Tables/)

Edit 2016:

You can now use flexbox vertically centre an element.

Answer (score 2):

Because the links (`a`) are `display: inline` by default.

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp) about the css `display` property. I guess you should use `display:block` oder `inline-block`.

To the second: Auto-margin never works if there's no width specified. Put the two `a`s into a `div` and set it's width to a fix value (or percentage which doesn't make any sense in your case).

```
#div-containing-the-as {
  width:300px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: width? I'm trying to vertically center, and it require's a width? I know that width would affect horizontally centering...

Comment: Also, changing them to block elements means that they can't both be on the same line...

Comment: inline-block is what I was looking for :)

Comment: @hahuang65 I misread this, but it should work analogically for vertical align, just set height.

Comment: actually false, does not working analogically for vertical align.